# Upload photo to arbitrary FTP with iPhone app

Tags: iphone, upload, ftp, photo

I'd like to upload a photo from my iphone to an arbitrary ftp.  How can I do this with Cocoa / Xcode ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into [CFFTPStream](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) in regard to the iPhone

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice framework out there called [ConnectionKit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/).  I haven't used it personally, but I've heard it's good.

Comment: I've been looking at it for use in an iPad app, and I it's too tied to Mac only frameworks to use.  Also, the code seems like it's not updated very often, especially the sample code, so I wasn't even able to get it running on the Mac.