# How to connect with FTP server?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uploading and downloading via ftp with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk)

I want to implement one application in which i want to connect ftp server from the iphone by programming.Please help me for that.

Edit:
I am using below code 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/

Its working fine.But when i am using my ftp server url at that time it gives open stream error.What is the problem can u explain me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128378/upload-photo-to-arbitrary-ftp-with-iphone-app

duplicate question

Comment: As well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk , although the sample code Adrian points to is new, and is the best resource for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a sample provided by Apple in the SDK documentation that does exactly that:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of information by googling "ftp protocol", but you you can [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc114) the RFC #114 which could be seen as the official specification of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 959 is the original standard for the FTP protocol. You can get a copy of this from this IETF Website. You can also download a free or free for personal use ftp server like filezilla or sysax [ftp server](http://www.sysax.com/server/) to use for testing your iphone program. Hope this helps.