# FTP downloads to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ftp

I have my own domain and ftp information, and I was wondering if there is a way to pull something off an ftp server (maybe a simple text file) and display it on my iPhone. What kind of objective C code is needed for this? I have developed a couple apps but have never dealt with networking, and now that I have a site, I would like to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: As I indicated in your [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074018/ftp-and-iphone-programming), this is a duplicate of this question: [How to connect with FTP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998122/how-to-connect-with-ftp-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start out with the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html). Using `NSURLConnection` and related classes, FTP downloads are definitely possible.