# FTP and iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, ftp

Can someone show me code that takes an image from a server and puts it into an image on the iPhone to display in a program. In particular, let's say my ftp server is at mydomain.com and my username is "name" and password is "password"

What would the code look like to take an image called "hello.png" of size 25x25 sitting on the server and using it in my iPhone app.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect with FTP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998122/how-to-connect-with-ftp-server)

Comment: See also [Uploading and downloading via ftp with iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk) and [Upload photo to arbitrary FTP with iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128378/upload-photo-to-arbitrary-ftp-with-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some code I wrote for a phonegap plugin that will download a file and save it locally

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSURLConnection and CFFTPStream APIs.

A good example is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243) on Apple's site.